# Lock the first line when doing diff between two files in vimdiff

Tags: vimdiff

I am trying to do a diff between a couple of csv files. I have performed `column -t -s","` on both the files to be able to compare better. The first row contains the column names and I want to lock it when I do vimdiff on the two files.

I did vimdiff on the two files and then `:1sp` on both the split windows to see the first row. When I do `$` I am able to move to the end of the line and all the splits move together. I can see the last column name.

However, when I move to the next page, the first line of the page gets displayed in the 1sp windows instead of the column names. I need the column names (first line of the file) to be fixed there with horizontal scrolling and no vertical scrolling so that the column name remains there when I move to the bottom of the file.

I have tried various versions of `:set noscb` and `:set scrollopt-=ver`, `:set scrollopt=hor`, `:set scrollopt=`, `:set scrollopt=hor,jump` but no luck. Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: There is no easy way. You would have to create a split window, that just contains the header lines. My [csv.vim](https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim/#header-lines) does it that way.